# Login-AzureRMAccount -Credential immediately expiring

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I'm working on some automation around azure, specifically logging in and getting secrets out of an established key vault.  I need to do this in a non-interactive script, but when I run Login-AzureRmAccount, the authentication seems to be immediately dropping:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host "Login Complete"

$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $Vault -Name $SecretName
```

This script outputs:

> Login Complete
>
> Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Login-AzureRmAccount to set up 
>   your Azure credentials.
>   At C:\temp\test.ps1:29 char:11
>   + $secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $Vault -Name $SecretName
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.GetAzureKeyVaultSecret

Comment: Are you trying to run this in Azure Automation the service?  (or some other automation system)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the functionality that is described in the official repository as "not yet supported" - here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2067) where you may see the (possible) reason why it is happening and here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/655) where the workaround is proposed. Basically, you need to use the certificate to authenticate instead of the credentials.